# Flutter: How do i disable double pressed on IconButton

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-navigation, flutter-onpressed

I have some `IconButton` in `persistentFooterButtons` that navigate to other screens but if I pressed double on any button and press the back button it redirects two times. if I pressed the button multiple times and press the back button it shows me the same page. so I want to click only one time and when it clicks and shows me the page the button will disable and won't press I think it works but I know how do I do that. please help me with that issue.

Here is my code:-

```
class Footer extends StatefulWidget {

Footer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_Footer createState() => _Footer();
}

class _Footer extends State<Footer>{

 bool _isButtonTapped1 = false;
 bool _isButtonTapped2 = false;
 bool _isButtonTapped3 = false;
 bool _isButtonTapped4 = false;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context){
   
  return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar:  AppBar()
    persistentFooterButtons: [

      Row(
       children: [

        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const CardApp()),
                  (Route<dynamic> route) => false);

          },
          icon: SvgPicture.asset(
          'assets/images/f_home.svg',
          ),
        ),
        Spacer(),
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Matches()),
            );
          },
          icon: SvgPicture.asset(
          'assets/images/f_fav.svg',
          ),
        ),
        Spacer(),
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Message()),
            );
          },
          icon: SvgPicture.asset(
          'assets/images/f_chat.svg',
          ),
        ),
        Spacer(),
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Favorites()),
            );
          },
          icon: SvgPicture.asset(
          'assets/images/f_star.svg',
          ),
        ),


       ]
      )
    ],
  ),
  );
 
 }

}
```

Here is my code of `persistentFooterButtons` which added four buttons and each button navigates its own screen.
please help me ho disable multiple `onPressed` on every button. if anyone knows please help me out

Comment: You can use timer and flags for manage click [see here](https://medium.com/@denesh.raymond/debouncing-clicks-in-flutter-a7c40813b8c6) or try [Debouncing](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_debounce).

Comment: thank you for the reply, I used  [debouncing](https://medium.com/@denesh.raymond/debouncing-clicks-in-flutter-a7c40813b8c6) but i dont understand how I navigate other screens and stop double click. because every click changes its state.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to prevent multiple press from user, in InkWell widget, use this:
onDoubleTap: (){},